# Tabelas distintas no Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

Tenho uma tabela onde eu salvo o idaluno e idconcedente, quero fazer um select que pega os dois ids vá em suas respectivas tabelas e peguem o alunonome e nomeconcedente. Como no codeigniter?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o código que você já tentou fazer e onde esta com dificuldade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu model, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
function get_lista(){
    $this->db->select('concendente.nome as nome_concedente, aluno.nome as nome_aluno, tabela.*');
    $this->db->join('concendente', 'tabela.idconcendente=concendente.id');
    $this->db->join('aluno', 'tabela.idaluno=aluno.id');
    return $this->db->get('tabela')->result();
}
```

Dessa maneira, fazemos dois joins, buscando a tabela concendente e a tabela aluno, e no select definimos o nome de cada um.

Comment: Obrigado, fiz como você disse e deu o resultado que eu queria.

Comment: @davidsonAlves ótimo, só aceita minha resposta como válida. Obrigado! :